# Crazy Facebook UI Dialog Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb.ui

So I cannot find any reason I am seeing the below behavior and if anybody has some insight it will be greatly appreciated.

Basically I am using the `FB.UI` from the JavaScript SDK to send a message to a user with a link. The link ends with a `Guid`, like `http://www.domainname.com/register/33a1a0ae-e0fe-4eb6-9bf9-146d5492e3d6`. This works sometimes, but occasionally fails with a generic 500 error from FB.

I have pulled out the `HTTP POST` request and have found a solution that I can recreate, unfortunately I cannot share the access code to allow SO users to actually run it (I replaced all sensitive parameters). Below are two identical requests that differ only in the `Guid`. The first succeeds every time and the second fails every time. I have numerous `Guid`s that are doing this which makes if unreliable.

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?access_token=XXX&api_key=XXX&app_id=XXX&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D5%23cb%3Df2cb8f5c1ca0402%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.domainname.com%252Ff350c0fd55d5764%26domain%3Dwww.domainname.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D5%23cb%3Df11a615f3b71192%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.domainname.com%252Ff350c0fd55d5764%26domain%3Dwww.domainname.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&description=test&display=iframe&link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domainname.com%2Fregister%2F**33a1a0ae-e0fe-4eb6-9bf9-146d5492e3d6**&locale=en_US&name=test&next=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D5%23cb%3Df22e359d88321ce%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.domainname.com%252Ff350c0fd55d5764%26domain%3Dwww.domainname.com%26relation%3Dparent%26frame%3Df33c13cd4ecc156%26result%3D%2522xxRESULTTOKENxx%2522&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domainname.com%2Fimg.gif&sdk=joey&to=XXX
>
> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?access_token=XXX&api_key=XXX&app_id=XXX&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D5%23cb%3Df2cb8f5c1ca0402%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.domainname.com%252Ff350c0fd55d5764%26domain%3Dwww.domainname.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D5%23cb%3Df11a615f3b71192%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.domainname.com%252Ff350c0fd55d5764%26domain%3Dwww.domainname.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&description=test&display=iframe&link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domainname.com%2FFregister%2F**dd171262-dbcc-43c3-b9d1-e37dc53e3520**&locale=en_US&name=test&next=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D5%23cb%3Df22e359d88321ce%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.domainname.com%252Ff350c0fd55d5764%26domain%3Dwww.domainname.com%26relation%3Dparent%26frame%3Df33c13cd4ecc156%26result%3D%2522xxRESULTTOKENxx%2522&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domainname.com%2Fimg.gif&sdk=joey&to=XXX

Comment: Can you maybe share a url that works and a url that does not?

Comment: @Nitzan Tomer, those links are correct. If you replace the "XXX" with valid access_token and app info it should be testable.

Comment: Well, the "dp,aomname" is confusing..  Anyhow, I tested both urls (www.domainname.com/Fregister/dd171262-dbcc-43c3-b9d1-e37dc53e3520 and   www.domainname.com/register/33a1a0ae-e0fe-4eb6-9bf9-146d5492e3d6) and both returned: 404 - Not Found

Comment: Those should all be www.domainname.com, I have placed put up the app on a staging site so if you can replace the domains with laine.webhop.org and the the link param with laine.webhop.org/tresendas/register/GUID. Replacing GUID with each guid above. Thanks!!!!

Comment: The urls http://laine.webhop.org/tresendas/register/33a1a0ae-e0fe-4eb6-9bf9-146d5492e3d6 and http://laine.webhop.org/tresendas/register/dd171262-dbcc-43c3-b9d1-e37dc53e3520 result in a server error (Server Error in '/Tresendas' Application). Maybe you can just post urls that work instead of me trying to figure out the urls myself?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding in what is the issue. The links above are what is sent to FB in the message, does it matter if they do not load correctly? If so I can make them work a bit later. The problem I am having is that the message errors out upon sending it in the FB.ui dialog. And again the only difference in either is the Guid itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested both of these urls:

- http://www.domainname.com/register/33a1a0ae-e0fe-4eb6-9bf9-146d5492e3d6
- http://www.domainname.com/register/dd171262-dbcc-43c3-b9d1-e37dc53e3520

with the js sdk send method, and indeed the first url resulted in a 500 from facebook, while the first managed to send it.
I can't understand why the first UID triggers an error while the second does not.

The reason I kept asking for a working example of such urls is that when you share a url using facebook, they scrap that url (unless it's already in their cache) and extract meta data of that url so that a feed story can be composed.

Since the urls that I was trying are not accessible for facebook it might somehow trigger that error.
If I try this url:
http://laine.webhop.org/tresendas/register/33a1a0ae-e0fe-4eb6-9bf9-146d5492e3d6
then it works and I don't get the server error, even though it has the same UID as the first url I tried.

I suggest that you try to use urls accessible to facebook, if you still get errors for certain UIDs, then you should probably open a new bug report.

Comment: Can you test something else, in the non-working example. Simply change the last character in the guid to something else like a 5. It then works, which neither of these should resolve.

Comment: I don't argue that it's not strange, what I'm saying is that this unexplained bug might not occur when the url is reachable by facebook (not 404), maybe this bug only happens when they try a fall back to when it's not reachable. If you try the failing UIDs with working urls, does it work or not?

Comment: You are 100% correct. Fixed the error on that page to allow for the loading of that page worked perfect. I am getting consistent results. Thanks!